# CSS animation isn't running seamlessy

Tags: css, animation

I have a simple animation where I want an object to float up and down by 2rem, seamlessly. But sometimes when it reaches the top/bottom position of the animation it pauses for like a second or two. Why is that? And what can I do to make the direct-change seamless and without pause?

```
.toBeAnimated{
  position: fixed;
  top: 60%;
  left: 80%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

  background-image: url(./static/image.svg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;

  animation-name: floatingUpAndDown;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
}

@keyframes floatingUpAndDown {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -2rem, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `will-change:transform`? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change)

Comment: Are you sure you're not just referring to the easing algorithm? That intentionally slows down/stops at the ends.

Comment: considering you're using transform instead of position, you're animating correctly. 
The animation duration is 10s, though, so the timing will be pretty slow at the end, resulting in a "choppy" look. Either lower the duration or change the timing function.

Comment: thanks for the help, what would I change the timing function to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **animation-timing-function** value **linear** instead of **ease**. Hope it will work.